# Using nested if or ifelse in Netlogo to specify probabilities

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I am having trouble using nested ifs in Netlogo to specify deer reproductive probabilities. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
to reproduce-adult
let chance-fawn random-float 1.001
let chance-to-reproduce .9 
let chance-for-one .3 
let chance-for-two .4 
let chance-for-three .02
  if any? femadults [
    ask femadults [
  if random-float 1.001 < chance-to-reproduce [
    if chance-fawn < chance-for-three
    [set births (births + 3)
      let new-offspring nobody
      hatch-infants 3
      [set new-offspring self set color red - 1 set size 1]
      set offspring new-offspring]
    if chance-fawn > chance-for-two
    [set births (births + 2)
      let new-offspring nobody
      hatch-infants 2
      [set new-offspring self set color red - 1 set size 1]
      set offspring new-offspring]
    if (chance-fawn > .02) and (chance-fawn < chance-for-one)
    [set births (births + 1)
      let new-offspring nobody
      hatch-infants 1
      [set new-offspring self set color red - 1 set size 1]
      set offspring new-offspring]
     ]]]
   end
```

Basically, the chance of a doe getting pregnant is 90%. So I want that if the doe gets pregnant, she either has 1, 2 or 3 fawns. The chance of having 1 fawn is 28%. The chance of having 2 fawns is 60%. The chance of having 3 fawns is 2%. The problem with my current code is that if "chance-fawn" is between .3 and .4, it is not accounted for in the if statements, when it should be part of the 60% of having 2 fawns. Is there a better way to do this, using either if statements or something else? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want with `ifelse`, but you may want to have a look at the `rnd` extension, as it simplifies this type of thing. Specifically, the [weighted-one-of-list command](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html#rnd:weighted-one-of-list) allows you to make roulette wheel selection where you assign different weights to different options. For an example, look at this setup:

```
extensions [ rnd ]
globals [ fawn-probs ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  set fawn-probs [ [ 1 0.31 ] [ 2 0.67 ] [ 3 0.02 ] ]
  set offspring-list-norm []
  set offspring-list-alt []
  reset-ticks
end
```

You've got a list called `fawn-probs` that groups the different probabilities to different birth events. Note that I've made them sum to 1 by dividing each by 0.9; as p._phidot_ pointed out, your original probabilities did not. Now, you can use `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` to have your turtles randomly choose the number of fawns, weighted appropriately, from the `fawn-probs` list.

```
to reproduce
  ask turtles [
    ; If a spawning event occurs
    if random-float 1 < 0.9 [  
      ; Select the number of fawns to spawn based on the weighted
      ; probability list 'fawn-probs'
      let num-to-spawn first rnd:weighted-one-of-list fawn-probs [ p -> last p ]
      hatch num-to-spawn [
        rt random 360 
        fd 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to have the 10% chance of no-birth bundled into the same list, you could skip the `if random-float ...` chunk and just do:

```
to reproduce-alternative
  set fawn-probs [ [ 0 0.1 ] [ 1 0.28 ] [ 2 0.6 ] [ 3 0.02 ] ]
  ask turtles [
    let num-to-spawn first rnd:weighted-one-of-list fawn-probs [ p -> last p ]
    hatch num-to-spawn [
      rt random 360
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Someone in my department pointed out my probabilities did not equal one and adjusted them so they would equal 1, and basically that solved the problem. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

ok.. here's my drawing (not to scale) :

```
   +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------->
   0.0      0.02      0.1       0.3       0.4       0.5
```

a number line.. after the 1st if, you covered :

```
   +=========+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------->
   0.0      0.02      0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5
```

on the 2nd if :

```
   +=========+---------+---------+---------+=========+=========>
   0.0      0.02      0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5
```

the 3rd if:

```
   +=========+=========+=========+---------+=========+=========>
   0.0      0.02      0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5
```

So, it is logical that your conditions DOESN'T covers 0.3 to 0.4 range. (:

Also note that if your random number generated is EXACTLY 0.02 for example.. the 1st if and the 3rd if will miss it too. unless you use something like `<=` or `>=`.

Hope that explains.. (:

Comment: Thank you for the visual, since my probabilities did not add to one it makes sense I would be missing a range. I've got it to work now!

Comment: Glad it helps. [ :